# combinatorial of $\binom{10^9} {r}$ while $1 \leq r \leq10^9 \pmod {10^6+3}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, combinations

How to calculate $ \binom{n}{r} \mod m$ when $1\leq n,\: r\leq 10^9$ and $m=10^6+3$.
I have tried by making Sieve of factorial and multiplicative inverse $10^6+3 \mod m$.
is there any solution in $\mathcal{O}(m)$?

Answer (score 2):

$10^6+3$ is a prime number

Using [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem):

$$\binom{n}{r} = \Pi_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n_i}{r_i}\ mod\ p$$

where $n,r$ are expressed as base $p$ expansion.

$n=n_0 + n_1p + n_2p^2 + .. + n_kp^k$

$r=r_0 + r_1p + r_2p^2 + .. + r_kp^k $

The coefficients can be  found in $O(log_k(n))$ and the number of $mod$ operations are bounded by $O(k)$ as long as $\binom{n_i}{r_i}$ can be determined in $O(1)$ probably using a lookup table.